# Multiple scenario in where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, where-clause, greatest-n-per-group

I have the following data:

```
Invoice | Status | StatusDate
1111111  BackOrd   null
1111111  Delivd    2020-01-01
2222222  BackOrd   null
3333333  Delivd    2020-02-29
```

In the above invoice 11111 was on BackOrd at one time and now has been Delivered, 222222 is currently on BackOrd and 33333 was never on BackOrd and was Delivered.  22222&33333 are easy but 11111 is vexing me because I would want to only show the current Status of Delivered.

I've tried

```
where case when StatusDate is null then 'BackOrd' else 'Delivd' end = Status
```

and various iterations, however my examples of 11111 will bring back both rows which sure is was in both at one time.  I feel like this shouldn't be that hard and maybe not enough coffee but something isn't making sense to me.

Comment: Please post what result you want?

Answer (score 2):

You want the latest row per `invoice`, so this is a top-1-per group problem. You can use window functions:

```
select *
from (
    select t.*,
        row_number() over(partition by invoice order by statusdate desc) rn
    from mytable t
) t
where rn = 1
```

This works because SQL Server puts `null` values last when using a descending sort.

Comment: Thank you.  That will work for me.  I had kind of thought about the same but your last sentence is what I couldn't work out if that would work.